# How to sum elements at the same index in separate arrays using for loop (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Given two arrays of integers:

```
const arr3 = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15,];
const arr4 = [16, 17, 18, 19, 20,];
```

Using For-Loop, how do I add up each element in the same position and
create a new array containing the sum of each pair?
Both arrays are of the same length.

Comment: If you post what you tried, someone may be able to help you fix/finish it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you share what you have tried so far?  Also, for what it is worth, this feels like it may be a homework question; if so, I'd recommend you review the post [How Do I Ask And Answer Homework Questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Use the `Array.prototype.map()` function. It receives the index as an argument, so it can use that to access the corresponding element in the second array.

Comment: *"Using For-Loop, how do I add up each element in the same position*". Yes, use a for loop through the array and get the value for the same index from both arrays and add them up. Which part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2):

```
var results = [];

for (var i=0; i < arr3.length; i++) {
  results.push(arr3[i] + arr4[i])
}
```